# Attributted String link not opening

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I need to set a couple of links on the click of an attributed string in a label/textview(UILabel is preferred). I used the following code for setting the links.(multiple links in same label).

```
NSMutableAttributedString  *firstAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"By tapping 'Yes', you agree to the " ];

NSMutableAttributedString  *secondAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Terms of Use "];
[firstAttributedString appendAttributedString:secondAttributedString];
NSMutableAttributedString  *thirdAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"and "];
[firstAttributedString appendAttributedString:thirdAttributedString];

NSMutableAttributedString  *fourthAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Privacy Policy "];
[firstAttributedString appendAttributedString:fourthAttributedString];

NSMutableAttributedString  *fifthAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"of example"];
[firstAttributedString appendAttributedString:fifthAttributedString];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"example://termsOfUse"];
[secondAttributedString addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: URL range: NSMakeRange(0, secondAttributedString.length)];
[alertTextView setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];
alertTextView.editable=NO;

alertTextView.attributedText = firstAttributedString;
alertTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

I have set my info.plist to respond to the url scheme call, but the method in the

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation`

delegate is not triggering. So I am assuming the click is not getting triggered. What am I doing wrong here? What can I do to solve this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1495/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Upon further review of your sample code, you are trying to modify `secondAttributedString` after it has been appended to `firstAttributedString`.  This will not produce the results you want, as NSAttributedStrings are *not* like Arrays.

Think of appending strings like appending a copy of whatever you pass in.

Try adding the link attributes *before* appending `secondAttributedString` to the first one.

```
NSMutableAttributedString  *firstAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"By tapping 'Yes', you agree to the " ];

NSMutableAttributedString  *secondAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Terms of Use "];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"example://termsOfUse"];
[secondAttributedString addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: URL range: NSMakeRange(0, secondAttributedString.length)];
[firstAttributedString appendAttributedString:secondAttributedString];


NSMutableAttributedString  *thirdAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"and "];
[firstAttributedString appendAttributedString:thirdAttributedString];
NSMutableAttributedString  *fourthAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Privacy Policy "];
[firstAttributedString appendAttributedString:fourthAttributedString];

NSMutableAttributedString  *fifthAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"of example"];
[firstAttributedString appendAttributedString:fifthAttributedString];
[alertTextView setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];
alertTextView.editable=NO;

alertTextView.attributedText = firstAttributedString;
```

---

Make sure your `UITextView` has the following properties set:

```
textView.editable = NO;
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
textView.delegate = self; // assuming `self` is the ViewController
```

You should instead implement the following [delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:):

```
textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:
```

and return `NO` and handle the action yourself.

Comment: The delegate method is not triggering and it still behaves the same

Comment: @AthiraKrishan ,in ViewDidload past this line textView.delegate = self;

Comment: @AthiraKrishnan after reviewing your code, I made an edit to my answer.  Try both parts.